# Сессии CodeIgniter 3.0

Tags: php, codeigniter

Доброго всем времени. Недавно начал изучать CodeI и при написании первой работы столкнулся со следующей проблемой: на странице логина пользователь вводит свои данные, которые проверяются соответствующим методом, после чего он либо перенаправляется в Личный кабинет, либо получает сообщение об ошибке. Структура сайта построена таким образом что в шапке отображается либо форма логина, либо приветствие пользователя. Так вот введя корректные данные пользователь успешно попадает в ЛК, но в шапке по прежнему отображается форма логина, до того момента пока пользователь либо не перегрузит страницу. либо не перейдет на другую страницу сайта... Кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой подскажите пожалуйста в чем тут дело. Кстати кнопка "Выход"(уничтожение текущей сессии) ведет себя так же.

Comment: TankAuth пробовали? https://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/

Comment: спасибо, за предложение, но проблема уже решена стандартной сессией CI, по неопытности запутался в логике. Внимательная проверка решила проблему.

Comment: Но теперь появился новый вопрос. Я использую сессии на основе драйвера БД. При создании сессии в файл data записывается только время последнего обновления сессии..Можно ли как-то настроить этот параметр и записывать туда еще и id или его нужно только вручную вытаскивать из БД?

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам. Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено в результате внимательной проверки и оказалось, что все дело в логике построения скрипта. Оказалось что у меня сначала создается переменная для работы с сессией и присваивается ей значение, а должно быть наоборот (сначала присвоение значений, а после проверка авторизован ли пользователь). Перестановка методов местами дала положительный результат.